# save/get data from map field type

Tags: 8

What I want to do is give a possibility to the user to save as many images as he likes. For this, I have created a specific field type

```
    $fields['photo_ids'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('map')
  ->setLabel(t('Photos'))
  ->setDescription(t('The photo ids of the Item entity.'))
  ->setSettings([
    'max_length' => 50,
    'text_processing' => 0,
  ])
  ->setDefaultValue('');
```

here I want to save, add, delete IDs of pictures. Not sure if this is the best approach to this problem. The problem is I can't find the way in Drupal 8 to serialize/deserialize and save these data into the database;

Comment: Sounds like a multi-value field?

Comment: yes I plan to store all picture ids in this field

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in field api and ui? Check "setCardinality" for your BaseFieldDefinition approach.

Comment: because I don't know about it :), could share an example or link of how to do it?

Comment: There are plenty on youtube. Search for something like "content type field create drupal 8".

Comment: The built-int field UI? You haven't seen that?

Comment: That all has a learning purpose, I am creating a new module and using entity type that's why I would like to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You should not create your content type programmatically, if there's no special reason. Take a look at any intro like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfu6nckjuno - then create a content type and fields with the excellent admin UI.

Serialization to DB is done by the Drupal core.